# Javascript - An array of object's value used the last value iterated

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to push objects to an empty array, where its `x` property value incremented on each loop. I used `console.log(B.x)` to check that it does iterate but even so, each object will have its `x` property value set to 300

**n = 20**, therefore, 100 (original x's value) + 10 (iteration) * 20 (loop) = 300

```
function createBlocks(n) {
  var blockArray = [];

  var B = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    color: "brown"
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    blockArray.push(B);
    B.x += 10;
    console.log(B.x);
    console.log(blockArray[i]);
  }
  return blockArray;
}
```

I don't understand why all the objects have the same value (300) for its `x`'s property.

Comment: Because objects are passed as reference not value. When you assign one object's value to another it will be referred not copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your object is single and you have multiple references to it. So why changing for one, it changes the actually object. You need to create separate objects for each item.

You can use **object destructing** to copy the properties from one object into a new object and push that `temp` object into the array.

```js
const blockArray = [];

const B = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  width: 35,
  height: 35,
  color: "brown"
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let temp = { ...B };
  blockArray.push(temp);   
  B.x += 10;
}
  
console.log(blockArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for this also:

```
function createBlocks(n) {
  const blockArray = [];

  const B = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    color: "brown"
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const temp = { ...B }; // object spread
    blockArray.push(temp);
    B.x += 10;
  }
  return blockArray;
}

createBlocks(20);
```